# Need long distance wifi

Tags: networking

I live 1/2 mile from nearest telephone line.  I have Dish internet, but it is very costly and after using 5gb is slows down tremendously. I looked on internet for solutions and I have found directional antennas but I am not very technical.  What would I need to send this signal from where I can get a telephone line to my house?

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2015/07/14/how-to-build-a-proxyham-despite-a-cancelled-defcon-talk/ this may be good for you and your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long range wifi details](http://superuser.com/questions/931319/long-range-wifi-details)

Answer (score 1):

Just like with regular Wi-Fi, you usually need an AP (access point) on the "provider" end, and at least one station (client) on the receiving end.

In general, searching for "WISP hardware" or "point to point wifi" should give you some results – there are products dedicated to this exact kind of use, commonly from Ubiquiti or Mikrotik, but I've also heard of LigoWave, Mimosa, and a few others. Some of those APs (e.g. [NanoStation](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanostationm/) or [LigoDLB](https://www.ligowave.com/products/dlb-5-90)) have built-in [patch](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Patch_antenna_pattern.gif) antennas good for 5–7 km, others (e.g. [Bullet](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/bulletm/)) need an [external](http://www.wifi-shop24.com/GOLD-Wireless-SAD56030-5-GHz-WiFi-Directional-Grid-Antenna-Outdoor-30dBi) directional antenna to be connected.

Other than the antennas, the configuration is more or less the same as with home routers – an Ethernet cable goes in to one end, SSID and channel are configured, and Wi-Fi signal comes out the other end (and the opposite on the clients).

That said, there is *one* thing to be aware of: While many of these products are *based on* standard Wi-Fi, they often default to using slightly modified, PtP-optimized protocols which only work between the same manufacturer's hardware. (For example, Ubiquiti calls theirs "airMAX".) If you mix manufacturers, you need to disable these protocols.

And first make sure to find someone who would agree to provide Internet for the AP...